# Why exception is not immediately thrown in Spark Dataframe show() on schema mismatch, if it's an action?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I'm using Java and

```
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.4.4'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.4'
```

I have a dataset of rows:

```
 Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().json(path);
```

Which I'm able to *show()* and *printShema()*;

Now I'm creating new Dataset of my POJOs:

```
  Dataset<MyPOJO> ds2 =
                ds
                  .select(col("myCol").as("customers"))
                  .as(Encoders.bean(MyPOJO.class));
```

MyPOJO has a field, `String[] customers`.

Now I do ds2.show() and ds2.printSchema():

```
+--------------------+
|           customers|
+--------------------+
|     [[NASA], [ORS]]|
 ....


root
 |-- customers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I can see a schema mismatch. In fact, `customers` is an array of arrays, and not an array. However, the exception is not thrown at this moment.

Now I'm trying to:

```
 ds2.filter((FilterFunction<MyPOJO>) (i -> i.customers.length == 1)).show();
```

And this is where an exception is thrown:

```
 Column 40: Cannot cast "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData" to "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"
```

I got what's the problem (schema mismatch) and fixed it with the help of *flatten()* function.

My question is: why the exception is not immediately thrown at the moment of the  `ds2.show()`, and dataframe is indeed printed, if show() is an action called on dataframe (df2) of POJOs with schema mismatch?

Comment: Speculation: Show. maps only first N rows. Maybe it doesn't get to your faulty row? Try printing more rows?

Comment: Another speculation. `show()` iterates on column values and executes the `toString()` method on each Java object that is not Null. That will always work. And since `show()` has no utility except for debugging, why run consistency checks??

Comment: @SašaZejnilović, no, I can see faulty row right away in the output.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter this one looks promising, can you elaborate ?

Comment: Well, if you are really curious you should inspect the source code by yourself...